# PhpStorm Inspect Code On Save

Tags: phpstorm

In Eclipse, for example, I can have it compile code automatically on save, which gives instant feedback regarding coding errors.  Is it possible to have PhpStorm run "Inspect Code" automatically any time I save?  I'm using the vim extension, and it's so much easier to type :wq than clicking through a menu and dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Well .. you have inspections on the scrollbar in real time. The `Inspect Code` is run on request only unfortunately (or [before Commit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/commit-changes-dialog.html?search=commit#d833780e237)).
2. I could not find any existing ticket for similar request -- if you wish, you can submit one yourself at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

   The best I have found is this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120207
3. You can assign any convenient to you shortcut to that `Code | Inspect Code...` in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- it's not ideal but decent workaround.
4. If you have `Inspection Results` tool window opened, you could jump into it and use `Rerun` action (`Ctrl+F5` here on Windows)